# How can I Receive a Large Data Stream through a Socket Connection - without TCPClient

Tags: c#, sockets

I have the Problem, that I want to send a large string through a SocketConnection, but I can't receive the string at once because the Network is limited to 1500 bytes, so how can I Receive all bytes over the Socket without using a TCPClient, or is that just impossible.

```
    public string ReceiveString(Socket connection)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1048576];
        int recBytes = connection.Receive(buffer);
        return UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, 0, recBytes);
    }
```

Thats, what i have so far.

If it isn't possible, to get it over the Socket, can I get the EndPoint out of the Socket to use TCPClient as "last Option"?

Comment: You'll have to literally implement [protocol level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model#Layer_4:_Transport_Layer) yourself to split data into packets and receive (concatenate) them.

Comment: You can't.  TCP breaks every message into datagrams ~1500 bytes.  You are using synchronous Receive() method when you should be using Asynchronous method.  You need to add a terminating character to your transmit function so the receive function can continue reading 1500 datagrams until the end characters is found.

Comment: Doesn't TCP has some kind of end sequence i meant, i heard something about \0 ?

Comment: @Silent3241 no, it does not. TCP has no concept of messages at all. Higher level application-defined protocols on top of TCP implement message framing.

Comment: @jdweng switching to asynchronous reading will not solve the problem. Synchronous reading will work just fine. The solution is to frame the string so the reader knows when to stop reading. Either 1) send the string length before sending the string, or 2) terminate the string with a unique delimiter that cannot appear in the string.

Comment: Using Synchronous method with large files will make the application hang.  I've seem to be the only one  telling people for years on websites to add byte count or terminate messages.  Glad other people are finally saying the same thing.  It doesn't seem the people answering questions really understand the 7 network layers.

Comment: @jdweng the app will hang only if a synchronous method is used in the main thread, do you never use worker threads? And plenty of answerers understand the networking layers and how to frame TCP messages. Maybe you just never see them..

Answer (score 3):

TCP is a byte stream, it has no concept of messages.  The size of the individual packets on the wire is irrelevant, it is just an implementation detail of the networking hardware.  TCP guarantees that what you send is what you receive (but there is no 1-to-1 relationship between the size of individual sends and the size of individual reads, like there is in UDP).

The solution requires the sender to frame the string data in such a way that allows the reader to know when to stop reading. Either:

1. send the string length before sending the string data. The reader can then read the length first and then read the specified number of following bytes.
2. a. terminate the string with a unique delimiter that cannot appear in the string itself. The reader can then keep reading until it encounters the delimiter.

   b. the delimiter can be closure of the connection. The reader can keep reading until a disconnect is detected.

Which solution you need to use depends on the particular protocol you are implementing.  #1 is best for binary protocols, and allows for efficient memory managent, whereas #2 is more suited to text-based protocols, or streaming protocols where the final length is not know ahead of time. Sometimes protocols have to resort to #2b (HTTP and FTP both utilize it as times) when #1 and #2a are not possible.

Comment: Or switch to a higher level protocol built atop TCP that implements messaging/framing for you.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you are probably thinking more of a premade library than a protocol. If you just design/adopt a messaging protocol, you still have to implement the code for sending and reading the message framing.

Comment: Well, I was thinking of "switch to HTTP" or similar. I.e. a protocol built atop TCP that already has a concept of messaging.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever that doesn't really change what I said. If you implement HTTP (or whatever) manually, you have to code the messaging logic yourself (and HTTP actually utilizes *all three* framing scenarios I mentioned in my answer) unless you use a premade library that handles the messaging details for you.

Comment: Okay, I think it's just a phrasing thing then. I meant "switch to a higher level protocol *and* use a premade implementation of that protocol".

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever OK

Comment: I have it no working with the TCP-Protokol, I made it with an own "End Sequence" but no i have the Problem, when i thest it over localhost or in my Private network it works all fine. But when it goes over the internet my packages are completly missorderd. Any Ideas why that could be?

Comment: @Silent3241 not without seeing your actual code, both sending and receiving. Please update your question.

Comment: @RemyLebeau now it completely works the most interresting part is, when i add the single Byte-Arrays, that I receive to an Byte-List via addRange, then it works over localhost and private network all fine. But over the Internet the list completly messes around and bring it completly out of Order. I exchanged the List now with an FileStream and it works all fine.

Comment: @Silent3241 that implies that you were not managing your data buffers correctly. But you never showed your updated code, like I asked you to. It's good that the you found something that works, but it makes me wonder if you really understand why it works.